# Issues with ASDF on Clisp

Tags: clisp, asdf

I'm trying to install s-xml (I'm heading towards s-xml-rpc) on clisp 2.49 on os x. I think I've got asdf install correctly. I can run:

```
    (asdf:asdf-version) 
    "2.014"
```

so I guess that bits installed ok. But when I run:

```
(asdf-install:install :s-xml)
```

this happens

```
Install where?
1) System-wide install: 
   System in /usr/local/asdf-install/site-systems/
   Files in /usr/local/asdf-install/site/ 
2) Personal installation: 
   System in /Users/mattyw/.asdf-install-dir/systems/
   Files in /Users/mattyw/.asdf-install-dir/site/ 
0) Abort installation.
 --> 1
;;; ASDF-INSTALL: Downloading 25612 bytes from http://common-lisp.net/project/s-xml/s-xml.tgz to /Users/mattyw/asdf-install-0.asdf-install-tmp ...
;;; ASDF-INSTALL: Downloading 186 bytes from http://common-lisp.net/project/s-xml/s-xml.tgz.asc to /Users/mattyw/asdf-install-1.asdf-install-tmp ...
;;; ASDF-INSTALL: Installing /Users/mattyw/asdf-install-0.asdf-install-tmp in /usr/local/asdf-install/site/, /usr/local/asdf-install/site-systems/
x s-xml/
x s-xml/ChangeLog
x s-xml/doc/
x s-xml/doc/index.html
x s-xml/doc/S-XML.html
x s-xml/doc/style.css
x s-xml/Makefile
x s-xml/s-xml.asd
x s-xml/src/
x s-xml/src/dom.lisp
x s-xml/src/lxml-dom.lisp
x s-xml/src/package.lisp
x s-xml/src/sxml-dom.lisp
x s-xml/src/xml-struct-dom.lisp
x s-xml/src/xml.lisp
x s-xml/test/
x s-xml/test/all-tests.lisp
x s-xml/test/ant-build-file.xml
x s-xml/test/counter.lisp
x s-xml/test/echo.lisp
x s-xml/test/plist.xml
x s-xml/test/remove-markup.lisp
x s-xml/test/simple.xml
x s-xml/test/test-lxml-dom.lisp
x s-xml/test/test-sxml-dom.lisp
x s-xml/test/test-xml-struct-dom.lisp
x s-xml/test/test-xml.lisp
x s-xml/test/tracer.lisp
x s-xml/test/xhtml-page.xml

*** - Component "s-xml" not found
The following restarts are available:
RETRY          :R1      Retry installation
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
```

What does it mean by component s-xml not found. It seems to suggest it hasn't actually installed anything. I've tried doing asdf-install:install via a http link and a downloaded tar zip and I always seem to end up in this state. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried doing the Personal Installation (option 2) and I can see that the files get downloaded. But the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is not a problem with ASDF. It's a problem with ASDF-install.

ASDF-install is not maintained anymore. Alternatives include quicklisp and clbuild. I'd recommend quicklisp to get started fast.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was able to install the vecto package from the example but s-xml and s-xml-rpc still seem to be silently doing nothing: [8]> (ql:quickload "s-xml-rpc")
To load "s-xml-rpc":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    s-xml-rpc
; Loading "s-xml-rpc"

("s-xml-rpc")
[9]> (require 's-xml-rpc)

*** - LOAD: A file with name S-XML-RPC does not exist
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `ASDF:*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*` variable is not set properly, so that ASDF is not checking the directories into which you have installed the s-xml library.  It actually looks like ASDF-INSTALL *is* functioning correctly, but not in such a way that ASDF can then find the installed systems.  What's in that variable?  Or are you using Faré's new ASDF configuration facility?  If so, are the directories `/usr/local/asdf-install/site-systems/` and `/Users/mattyw/.asdf-install-dir/systems/` in your asdf search path?  Finally, have you looked in those directories and verified that the files have actually shown up there?